# Integral over Matrixfunction

Tags: matrix-calculus

I need to work out the Integral $$\int \frac{1}{(x\mathbb{1}-A)^2}B\frac{1}{x\mathbb{1}-C}\ dx$$
Where $A,B,C$ are matrices which generally do not commute and $x$ is real. $\mathbb{1}$ denotes the identity matrix. I am ok with using matrix functions like $\log(x-A)$ defined by their taylor expansion.

The result in the commutative case is obvious, but I am not sure how to generalize to the non commuting case.

Comment: By $x1$ do you mean $x^1 = x$?  If not, then what?  By the way, *Hagadol* is quite a moniker; *yitgadol yitkaddash sh'meh rabbah!*  Chappy Chanukah and other Seasonal Greetings!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you four your nice comment! I now added, the $\mathbb{1}$ is supposed to be the unity matrix.

Comment: You are more than welcome!  By the way, most folks would use $I$ instead of $1$ for the identity matrix, just so you know.  *Baruch HaShem!*